# Inhibit SIGINT for the process in group

Tags: bash, sigint

I have a bash script, which start 2 processes:

```
openocd ...flags... 2>openocd.log &
arm-none-eabi-gdb
```

When in gdb, interrupting execution with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> causes openocd to receive SIGINT as well and, thus it stops. I've tried to trap and reissue SIGINT directly to gdb with:

```
trap 'kill 2 $!' INT
```

But apart from requiring root, it does not work anyway:

```
./dbg.sh: 1: kill: No such process
```

Are there elegant ways to perform the task?

__

Well, running script with debug options on helped a lot. But still I encounter weird behavior. Here is the content of my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -vx
trap 'killall -s2 arm-none-eabi-gdb-py' 2
openocd -f ...flags... 2>openocd.log & arm-none-eabi-gdb-py
```

When I run killall -s2 arm-none-eabi-gdb-py from within different tty - it terminates execution of remote target and does not close openocd, but sending SIGINT through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> returns:

```
+ killall -s2 arm-none-eabi-gdb-py
arm-none-eabi-gdb-py: no process found
```

Seems like trap does not inhibit signals at all... changing to trap 'ps -ef' INT reveals, openocd AND gdb are already down when the trap command executes.

Comment: try making it all one script (with the `trap` included), and adding `set -vx` before the `trap` to see what is getting set when. I'm not sure that `set -vx` will emit the `trap` trace, but it's worth trying. Good luck.

Comment: `kill 2 $!` should be `kill -2 $!`.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't there a missing '&' in your instruction (it would give that)?

```
openocd -f ...flags... 2>openocd.log &**&** arm-none-eabi-gdb-py
```

Comment: No, `&` is correct. `&` causes `openocd` to run in the background (as opposed to `;` which runs it in the foreground).

Comment: So why there is a arm-none-eabi-gdb-py command just after on the same line?
I mean, it looks strange and could be different from what intended the author of the question.

Comment: That's how you run two commands simultaneously. There doesn't need to be a newline after the `&`, it's optional.